# Fit Table to specific page

Tags: tables, header-footer, fit

I have begun to  compile an appendix for my dissertation and the first I want to include uses the `begin{sidewaystable}`command. However, due to the size of the table it doesn't fit on the same page as the Appendix title, as shown below:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[margin=1in, left=1.5in, includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{here}
\usepackage{siunitx}                        % added
\usepackage{threeparttable}   
 \newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}    
 \titleformat*{\subsection}{\normalfont\large\itshape}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\footnoterule{
 \kern-3\p@
 \hrule\@width \textwidth
\kern2.6\p@}
\makeatother
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[R]{ \thepage\ }
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\usepackage{rotating}
\begin{document}
\appendix
\section{Appendix}\label{Appendix}
\newgeometry{ top=0.6cm, bottom=0.6cm, right=0.5cm, left=0.5cm}
\begin{centering}
\begin{sidewaystable}
\makebox[\textwidth]{%
\begin{tabular}{rrccccccccr}
\multicolumn{1}{l}{Country} &       & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Income Group} & Income Group 2005 & Income Group 2009 & CPI 2002 & CPI 2005 & CPI 2009 & EU Member & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Frequency} \\
\midrule
      &       & \multicolumn{2}{c}{} &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{Albania} &       & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Low-Middle} & Low-Middle & Upper-Middle & 2.5   & 2.4   & 3.2   &       & 732 \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{Belarus} &       & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Low-Middle} & Low-Middle & Upper-Middle & 4.8   & 2.6   & 2.4   &       & 848 \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{Georgia} &       & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Low } & Low-Middle & Low-Middle & 2.4   & 2.3   & 4.1   &       & 747 \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{Tajikistan} &       & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Low } & Low   & Low   &       & 2.1   & 2.0   &       & 733 \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{Ukraine} &       & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Low-Middle} & Low-Middle & Low-Middle & 2.4   & 2.6   & 2.2   &       & 1908 \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{Uzbekhistan} &       & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Low } & Low   & Low-Middle & 2.9   & 2.2   & 1.7   &       & 926 \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{Russia} &       & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Low-Middle} & Upper-Middle & Upper-Middle & 2.7   & 2.4   & 2.2   &       & 2111 \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{Poland} &       & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Upper-Middle} & Upper-Middle & High  & 4.0   & 3.4   & 5.0   & Yes   & 1928 \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{Romania} &       & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Low-Middle} & Upper-Middle & Upper-Middle & 2.6   & 3.0   & 3.8   & Yes   & 1396 \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{Serbia} &       & \multicolumn{2}{c}{-} & -     & Upper-Middle &       & 2.8   & 3.5   &       & 901 \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{Kazakstan } &       & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Low-Middle} & Low-Middle & Upper-Middle & 2.3   & 2.6   & 2.7   &       & 1379 \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{Moldova} &       & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Low} & Low-Middle & Low-Middle & 2.1   & 2.9   & 3.3   &       & 887 \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{Bosnia \& Herzegovina} &       & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Low-Middle} & Low-Middle & Upper-Middle &       & 2.9   & 3.0   &       & 743 \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{Azerbaijan} &       & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Low} & Low-Middle & Upper-Middle & 2     & 2.2   & 2.3   &       & 900 \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{Macedonia (FYROM)} &       & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Low-Middle} & Low-Middle & Upper-Middle &       & 2.7   & 3.8   &       & 736 \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{Armenia} &       & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Low-Middle} & Low-Middle & Low-Middle &       & 2.9   & 2.7   &       & 896 \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{Kyrgyzstan } &       & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Low} & Low   & Low   &       & 2.3   & 1.9   &       & 610 \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{Estonia} &       & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Upper-Middle} & Upper-Middle & High  & 5.6   & 6.4   & 6.6   & Yes   & 662 \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{Czech Republic} &       & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Upper-Middle} & Upper-Middle & High  & 3.7   & 4.3   & 4.9   & Yes   & 859 \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{Hungary} &       & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Upper-Middle} & Upper-Middle & High  & 4.9   & 5.0   & 5.1   & Yes   & 1151 \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{Lativa} &       & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Upper-Middle} & Upper-Middle & High  & 3.7   & 4.2   & 4.5   & Yes   & 651 \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{Lithuania} &       & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Upper-Middle} & Upper-Middle & Upper-Middle & 4.8   & 4.8   & 4.9   & Yes   & 681 \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{Slovakia} &       & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Upper-Middle} & Upper-Middle & High  & 3.7   & 4.3   & 4.5   & Yes   & 665 \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{Slovenia} &       & \multicolumn{2}{c}{High} & High  & High  & 6.0   & 6.1   & 6.6   & Yes   & 687 \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{Bulgaria} &       & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Low-Middle} & Low-Middle & Upper-Middle & 4.0   & 4     & 3.8   & Yes   & 1853 \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{Croatia} &       & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Upper-Middle} & Upper-Middle & High  & 3.8   & 3.4   & 4.1   & Yes   & 1160 \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{Montenegro} &       & \multicolumn{2}{c}{-} & -     & Upper-Middle &       & 2.8   & 3.9   &       & 153 \\
\midrule
      &       & \multicolumn{2}{c}{} &       &       &       &       &       & Total & 26903 \\
 \bottomrule
\end{tabular}}%
\caption{Countries in Sample}
\end{sidewaystable}
\label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{centering}
\end{document}
```

I have tried to redefine the margins using `newgeometry` but this hasn't helped and loses the format used in the rest of the document. Any help would be greatly appreciated - thanks in advance.

[image]

[image]

Comment: A `sidewaystable` is *always* placed on a new page as far as I know, regardless of the size of it's content. See if https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/69287/586 helps.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's yet another solution. It focuses on really organizing and grouping the material in the header row, to make it easier on the reader to figure out what the numbers are all about. (Incidentally, I think the header "CPI" is too terse and actually misleading; better to use "CPI Inflation", right?)

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
% I've reduced the preamble to the bare minimum
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{booktabs,caption,siunitx,rotating}
\usepackage[margin={1in},{left=1.1in},includefoot,letterpaper]{geometry}
\begin{document}

\appendix
\section{Appendix}

\begin{table}[!ht]
\centering
\begin{sideways}
\small
\begin{minipage}{0.85\textheight}
\begin{tabular}{@{} l *{3}{c}
                *{3}{S[table-format=1.1]} 
                c S[table-format=5.0]
                @{}}
\toprule
Country & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Income Group}  
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{CPI Inflation}
& \smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}EU\\Member\end{tabular}}  & {Freq.}\\
\cmidrule(lr){2-4} \cmidrule(lr){5-7}
& 2002 & 2005 & 2009 & {2002} & {2005} & {2009} & \\
\midrule
Albania     & Low-Middle    & Low-Middle    & Upper-Middle  & 2.5   & 2.4   & 3.2   &       & 732  \\
Belarus     & Low-Middle    & Low-Middle    & Upper-Middle  & 4.8   & 2.6   & 2.4   &       & 848  \\
Georgia     & Low           & Low-Middle    & Low-Middle    & 2.4   & 2.3   & 4.1   &       & 747  \\
Tajikistan  & Low           & Low           & Low           &       & 2.1   & 2.0   &       & 733  \\
Ukraine     & Low-Middle    & Low-Middle    & Low-Middle    & 2.4   & 2.6   & 2.2   &       & 1908 \\
Uzbekhistan & Low           & Low           & Low-Middle    & 2.9   & 2.2   & 1.7   &       & 926  \\
Russia      & Low-Middle    & Upper-Middle  & Upper-Middle  & 2.7   & 2.4   & 2.2   &       & 2111 \\
Poland      & Upper-Middle  & Upper-Middle  & High          & 4.0   & 3.4   & 5.0   & Yes   & 1928 \\
Romania     & Low-Middle    & Upper-Middle  & Upper-Middle  & 2.6   & 3.0   & 3.8   & Yes   & 1396 \\
Serbia      &               & -             & Upper-Middle  &       & 2.8   & 3.5   &       & 901  \\
Kazakstan   & Low-Middle    & Low-Middle    & Upper-Middle  & 2.3   & 2.6   & 2.7   &       & 1379 \\
Moldova     & Low           & Low-Middle    & Low-Middle    & 2.1   & 2.9   & 3.3   &       & 887  \\
Bosnia \& Herzegovina
            & Low-Middle    & Low-Middle    & Upper-Middle  &       & 2.9   & 3.0   &       & 743  \\
Azerbaijan  & Low           & Low-Middle    & Upper-Middle  & 2     & 2.2   & 2.3   &       & 900  \\
Macedonia (FYROM)
            & Low-Middle    & Low-Middle    & Upper-Middle  &       & 2.7   & 3.8   &       & 736  \\
Armenia     & Low-Middle    & Low-Middle    & Low-Middle    &       & 2.9   & 2.7   &       & 896  \\
Kyrgyzstan  & Low           & Low           & Low           &       & 2.3   & 1.9   &       & 610  \\
Estonia     & Upper-Middle  & Upper-Middle  & High          & 5.6   & 6.4   & 6.6   & Yes   & 662  \\
Czech Republic
            & Upper-Middle  & Upper-Middle  & High          & 3.7   & 4.3   & 4.9   & Yes   & 859  \\
Hungary     & Upper-Middle  & Upper-Middle  & High          & 4.9   & 5.0   & 5.1   & Yes   & 1151 \\
Lativa      & Upper-Middle  & Upper-Middle  & High          & 3.7   & 4.2   & 4.5   & Yes   & 651  \\
Lithuania   & Upper-Middle  & Upper-Middle  & Upper-Middle  & 4.8   & 4.8   & 4.9   & Yes   & 681  \\
Slovakia    & Upper-Middle  & Upper-Middle  & High          & 3.7   & 4.3   & 4.5   & Yes   & 665  \\
Slovenia    & High          & High          & High          & 6.0   & 6.1   & 6.6   & Yes   & 687  \\
Bulgaria    & Low-Middle    & Low-Middle    & Upper-Middle  & 4.0   & 4     & 3.8   & Yes   & 1853 \\
Croatia     & Upper-Middle  & Upper-Middle  & High          & 3.8   & 3.4   & 4.1   & Yes   & 1160 \\
Montenegro  & --            & --            & Upper-Middle  &       & 2.8   & 3.9   &       & 153  \\
\cmidrule(l){9-9}
\multicolumn{8}{r@{}}{Total:} & 26903 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Countries in Sample}
\end{minipage}
\end{sideways}
\end{table}
    \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: (+1) Fine idea for the headings!

Comment: :-) ............

Answer (score 5):

I would redesign you MWE as follows:

- clean-up the preamble (remove all twice loaded package)
- group packages according their purposes (all packages relevant for tables and math are loaded together)
- use package `makecell` for writing columns headers in two lines (by this shrink table width)
- rotate table with `sideways`, but note: `tabular` and `caption` had to be encapsulated together in `parbox` or `minipage`

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{mathtools,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, tabularx, threeparttable}
    \newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}
    \renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[showframe, % only for this case, in real document should be deleted
            hmargin={1.5in, 1in}, vmargin={1in, 1in}, includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing

\usepackage{here}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{siunitx}                        
\usepackage{rotating}

\begin{document}

\appendix
\section{Appendix}\label{Appendix}
    \begin{table}[!ht]
    \centering
\begin{sideways}
    \small
\begin{minipage}{0.9\textheight}
    \begin{tabular}{*{4}{l}
                    *{3}{S[table-format=1.1]} 
                         c 
                         S[table-format=4.0]
                    }
\thead[l]{Country}     
            & \thead{Income Group\\ 2002}  
                            & \thead{Income Group\\ 2005} 
                                            & \thead{Income Group\\ 2009} 
                                                            & {\thead{CPI\\ 2002}} 
                                                                    & {\thead{CPI\\ 2005}}
                                                                            & {\thead{CPI\\ 2009}}
                                                                                    & {\thead{EU\\ Member}} 
                                                                                            & {\thead{Frequency}} \\
    \midrule
Albania     & Low-Middle    & Low-Middle    & Upper-Middle  & 2.5   & 2.4   & 3.2   &       & 732  \\
Belarus     & Low-Middle    & Low-Middle    & Upper-Middle  & 4.8   & 2.6   & 2.4   &       & 848  \\
Georgia     & Low           & Low-Middle    & Low-Middle    & 2.4   & 2.3   & 4.1   &       & 747  \\
Tajikistan  & Low           & Low           & Low           &       & 2.1   & 2.0   &       & 733  \\
Ukraine     & Low-Middle    & Low-Middle    & Low-Middle    & 2.4   & 2.6   & 2.2   &       & 1908 \\
Uzbekhistan & Low           & Low           & Low-Middle    & 2.9   & 2.2   & 1.7   &       & 926  \\
Russia      & Low-Middle    & Upper-Middle  & Upper-Middle  & 2.7   & 2.4   & 2.2   &       & 2111 \\
Poland      & Upper-Middle  & Upper-Middle  & High          & 4.0   & 3.4   & 5.0   & Yes   & 1928 \\
Romania     & Low-Middle    & Upper-Middle  & Upper-Middle  & 2.6   & 3.0   & 3.8   & Yes   & 1396 \\
Serbia      &               & -             & Upper-Middle  &       & 2.8   & 3.5   &       & 901  \\
Kazakstan   & Low-Middle    & Low-Middle    & Upper-Middle  & 2.3   & 2.6   & 2.7   &       & 1379 \\
Moldova     & Low           & Low-Middle    & Low-Middle    & 2.1   & 2.9   & 3.3   &       & 887  \\
Bosnia \& Herzegovina
            & Low-Middle    & Low-Middle    & Upper-Middle  &       & 2.9   & 3.0   &       & 743 \\
Azerbaijan  & Low           & Low-Middle    & Upper-Middle  & 2     & 2.2   & 2.3   &       & 900 \\
Macedonia (FYROM)
            & Low-Middle    & Low-Middle    & Upper-Middle  &       & 2.7   & 3.8   &       & 736 \\
Armenia     & Low-Middle    & Low-Middle    & Low-Middle    &       & 2.9   & 2.7   &       & 896 \\
Kyrgyzstan  & Low           & Low           & Low           &       & 2.3   & 1.9   &       & 610 \\
Estonia     & Upper-Middle  & Upper-Middle  & High          & 5.6   & 6.4   & 6.6   & Yes   & 662 \\
Czech Republic
            & Upper-Middle  & Upper-Middle  & High          & 3.7   & 4.3   & 4.9   & Yes   & 859 \\
Hungary     & Upper-Middle  & Upper-Middle  & High          & 4.9   & 5.0   & 5.1   & Yes   & 1151 \\
Lativa      & Upper-Middle  & Upper-Middle  & High          & 3.7   & 4.2   & 4.5   & Yes   & 651 \\
Lithuania   & Upper-Middle  & Upper-Middle  & Upper-Middle  & 4.8   & 4.8   & 4.9   & Yes   & 681 \\
Slovakia    & Upper-Middle  & Upper-Middle  & High          & 3.7   & 4.3   & 4.5   & Yes   & 665 \\
Slovenia    & High          & High          & High          & 6.0   & 6.1   & 6.6   & Yes   & 687 \\
Bulgaria    & Low-Middle    & Low-Middle    & Upper-Middle  & 4.0   & 4     & 3.8   & Yes   & 1853 \\
Croatia     & Upper-Middle  & Upper-Middle  & High          & 3.8   & 3.4   & 4.1   & Yes   & 1160 \\
Montenegro  & -             & -             & Upper-Middle  &       & 2.8   & 3.9   &       & 153 \\
    \midrule
            &               &               &               &       &       &       & Total & 26903\\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
    \caption{Countries in Sample}
    \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{minipage}
\end{sideways}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/25Kl]

**Edit:**
in original answer I incidentally delete part of first column header. Now this is corrected. Also the column headers can be reorganized as *suggested* Bernard in his first example and also *Mico* in his answer. On this part of table design I forgot when I "cleaning-up" your MWE :(. Now I also move `\label˙on the place where it should be: immediately after`caption`.

**Addendum:**
new example with in comparison to above has redesigned column headers, grouped rows for more easy reading, form similar as we learn in grammar school, without use of the `makecell` package. For exercise, fun and to see one more alternative ...

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{mathtools,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx, threeparttable}
    \newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[showframe, % only for this case, in real document should be deleted
            hmargin={1.5in, 1in}, vmargin={1in, 1in}, includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing

\usepackage{here}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{siunitx}                        
\usepackage{rotating}

\begin{document}

\appendix
\section{Appendix}\label{Appendix}
    \begin{table}[!ht]
    \centering
    \captionsetup{skip=1ex}
\begin{sideways}
    \small
\begin{minipage}{0.85\textheight}
    \begin{tabular}{*{4}{l}
                    *{3}{S[table-format=1.1]} 
                         c 
                         S[table-format=4.0]
                    }
            & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Income Group}              & \multicolumn{3}{c}{CPI}
                                                                                    & {EU}  &       \\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-4}\cmidrule(lr){5-7}
Country     & 2002          & 2005          & 2009          & {2002}& {2005}& {2009}& {Member}
                                                                                            & {Frequency}   \\
    \midrule
Albania     & Low-Middle    & Low-Middle    & Upper-Middle  & 2.5   & 2.4   & 3.2   &       & 732  \\
Belarus     & Low-Middle    & Low-Middle    & Upper-Middle  & 4.8   & 2.6   & 2.4   &       & 848  \\
Georgia     & Low           & Low-Middle    & Low-Middle    & 2.4   & 2.3   & 4.1   &       & 747  \\
Tajikistan  & Low           & Low           & Low           &       & 2.1   & 2.0   &       & 733  \\
    \addlinespace
Ukraine     & Low-Middle    & Low-Middle    & Low-Middle    & 2.4   & 2.6   & 2.2   &       & 1908 \\
Uzbekhistan & Low           & Low           & Low-Middle    & 2.9   & 2.2   & 1.7   &       & 926  \\
Russia      & Low-Middle    & Upper-Middle  & Upper-Middle  & 2.7   & 2.4   & 2.2   &       & 2111 \\
Poland      & Upper-Middle  & Upper-Middle  & High          & 4.0   & 3.4   & 5.0   & Yes   & 1928 \\
    \addlinespace
Romania     & Low-Middle    & Upper-Middle  & Upper-Middle  & 2.6   & 3.0   & 3.8   & Yes   & 1396 \\
Serbia      &               & -             & Upper-Middle  &       & 2.8   & 3.5   &       & 901  \\
Kazakstan   & Low-Middle    & Low-Middle    & Upper-Middle  & 2.3   & 2.6   & 2.7   &       & 1379 \\
Moldova     & Low           & Low-Middle    & Low-Middle    & 2.1   & 2.9   & 3.3   &       & 887  \\
    \addlinespace
Bosnia \& Herzegovina
            & Low-Middle    & Low-Middle    & Upper-Middle  &       & 2.9   & 3.0   &       & 743 \\
Azerbaijan  & Low           & Low-Middle    & Upper-Middle  & 2     & 2.2   & 2.3   &       & 900 \\
Macedonia (FYROM)
            & Low-Middle    & Low-Middle    & Upper-Middle  &       & 2.7   & 3.8   &       & 736 \\
Armenia     & Low-Middle    & Low-Middle    & Low-Middle    &       & 2.9   & 2.7   &       & 896 \\
    \addlinespace
Kyrgyzstan  & Low           & Low           & Low           &       & 2.3   & 1.9   &       & 610 \\
Estonia     & Upper-Middle  & Upper-Middle  & High          & 5.6   & 6.4   & 6.6   & Yes   & 662 \\
Czech Republic
            & Upper-Middle  & Upper-Middle  & High          & 3.7   & 4.3   & 4.9   & Yes   & 859 \\
Hungary     & Upper-Middle  & Upper-Middle  & High          & 4.9   & 5.0   & 5.1   & Yes   & 1151 \\
    \addlinespace
Lativa      & Upper-Middle  & Upper-Middle  & High          & 3.7   & 4.2   & 4.5   & Yes   & 651 \\
Lithuania   & Upper-Middle  & Upper-Middle  & Upper-Middle  & 4.8   & 4.8   & 4.9   & Yes   & 681 \\
Slovakia    & Upper-Middle  & Upper-Middle  & High          & 3.7   & 4.3   & 4.5   & Yes   & 665 \\
Slovenia    & High          & High          & High          & 6.0   & 6.1   & 6.6   & Yes   & 687 \\
    \addlinespace
Bulgaria    & Low-Middle    & Low-Middle    & Upper-Middle  & 4.0   & 4     & 3.8   & Yes   & 1853 \\
Croatia     & Upper-Middle  & Upper-Middle  & High          & 3.8   & 3.4   & 4.1   & Yes   & 1160 \\
Montenegro  & -             & -             & Upper-Middle  &       & 2.8   & 3.9   &       & 153 \\
    \midrule
            &               &               &               &       &       &       & Total & 26903\\
    \cmidrule[1pt]{9-9}
\end{tabular}
    \caption{Countries in Sample}
    \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{minipage}
\end{sideways}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Should the label be within the minipage with the caption?

Comment: @Zarko: I see we had almost the same idea!

Comment: @Troy, yes, but after `\caption` :)

Comment: @Bernard, I notice now, but there are some subtle differences :). Your answer is very nice!

Answer (score 5):

I propose two solutions, based on `adjustbox` and `makecell`, without having to use `newgeometry`, which creates automatically a newpage:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[margin=1in, left=1.5in, includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
\usepackage{float, makecell}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{siunitx} % added
\usepackage{threeparttable}
 \newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}
 \titleformat*{\subsection}{\normalfont\large\itshape}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\footnoterule{
 \kern-3\p@
 \hrule\@width \textwidth
\kern2.6\p@}
\makeatother
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[R]{ \thepage\ }
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\begin{document}

\appendix

\section{Appendix}\label{Appendix}

\adjustbox{rotate=-90, scale={-1}{-1}, center}
{%
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{5pt}%
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize}
\renewcommand\theadalign{bc}
\parbox{\textheight}{\centering
\begin{tabular}{l@{\qquad}*{7}{c}@{\qquad}S[table-format=5.0]}
Country & Income Group &\thead{ Income Group\\ 2005} & \thead{Income Group\\ 2009} & \thead{CPI\\ 2002} & \thead{CPI\\ 2005} &\thead{ CPI\\ 2009} & \thead{EU\\ Member} & {Frequency} \\
\midrule
\addlinespace
Albania & Low-Middle & Low-Middle & Upper-Middle & 2.5 & 2.4 & 3.2 & & 732 \\
Belarus & Low-Middle & Low-Middle & Upper-Middle & 4.8 & 2.6 & 2.4 & & 848 \\
Georgia & Low & Low-Middle & Low-Middle & 2.4 & 2.3 & 4.1 & & 747 \\
Tajikistan & Low & Low & Low & 2.1 & 2.0 & & & 733 \\
Ukraine & Low-Middle & Low-Middle & Low-Middle & 2.4 & 2.6 & 2.2 & & 1908 \\
Uzbekhistan & Low & Low & Low-Middle & 2.9 & 2.2 & 1.7 & & 926 \\
Russia & Low-Middle & Upper-Middle & Upper-Middle & 2.7 & 2.4 & 2.2 & & 2111 \\
Poland & Upper-Middle & Upper-Middle & High & 4.0 & 3.4 & 5.0 & Yes & 1928 \\
Romania & Low-Middle & Upper-Middle & Upper-Middle & 2.6 & 3.0 & 3.8 & Yes & 1396 \\
Serbia & — & — & Upper-Middle & & 2.8 & 3.5 & & 901 \\
Kazakstan & Low-Middle & Low-Middle & Upper-Middle & 2.3 & 2.6 & 2.7 & & 1379 \\
Moldova & Low & Low-Middle & Low-Middle & 2.1 & 2.9 & 3.3 & & 887 \\
Bosnia \& Herzegovina & Low-Middle & Low-Middle & Upper-Middle & & 2.9 & 3.0 & & 743 \\
Azerbaijan & Low & Low-Middle & Upper-Middle & 2 & 2.2 & 2.3 & & 900 \\
Macedonia (FYROM) & Low-Middle & Low-Middle & Upper-Middle & & 2.7 & 3.8 & & 736 \\
Armenia & Low-Middle & Low-Middle & Low-Middle & & 2.9 & 2.7 & & 896 \\
Kyrgyzstan & Low & Low & Low & & 2.3 & 1.9 & & 610 \\
Estonia & Upper-Middle & Upper-Middle & High & 5.6 & 6.4 & 6.6 & Yes & 662 \\
Czech Republic & Upper-Middle & Upper-Middle & High & 3.7 & 4.3 & 4.9 & Yes & 859 \\
Hungary & Upper-Middle & Upper-Middle & High & 4.9 & 5.0 & 5.1 & Yes & 1151 \\
Lativa & Upper-Middle & Upper-Middle & High & 3.7 & 4.2 & 4.5 & Yes & 651 \\
Lithuania & Upper-Middle & Upper-Middle & Upper-Middle & 4.8 & 4.8 & 4.9 & Yes & 681 \\
Slovakia & Upper-Middle & Upper-Middle & High & 3.7 & 4.3 & 4.5 & Yes & 665 \\
Slovenia & High & High & High & 6.0 & 6.1 & 6.6 & Yes & 687 \\
Bulgaria & Low-Middle & Low-Middle & Upper-Middle & 4.0 & 4 & 3.8 & Yes & 1853 \\
Croatia & Upper-Middle & Upper-Middle & High & 3.8 & 3.4 & 4.1 & Yes & 1160 \\
Montenegro & — & — & Upper-Middle & & 2.8 & 3.9 & & 153 \\
\midrule
      & & & & & & & Total & 26903 \\
 \bottomrule
\end{tabular}%
\captionof{table}{Countries in Sample}\label{tab:addlabel}}
}%

%%
\section{Appendix}\label{AppendixB}
\centering
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}%
\adjustbox{rotate = -90, scale={-1}{-1}, center}{%
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{5pt}\small%
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small}
\renewcommand\theadalign{bc}
\begin{tabular}{l@{\qquad}*{7}{c}@{\qquad}S[table-format=5.0]}
Country & Income Group & \thead{Income Group\\ 2005} & \thead{Income Group\\ 2009} & \thead{CPI \\ 2002} & \thead{CPI\\ 2005} &\thead{CPI\\ 2009} & \thead{EU\\ Member} & {Frequency} \\
\midrule
\addlinespace
Albania & Low-Middle & Low-Middle & Upper-Middle & 2.5 & 2.4 & 3.2 & & 732 \\
Belarus & Low-Middle & Low-Middle & Upper-Middle & 4.8 & 2.6 & 2.4 & & 848 \\
Georgia & Low & Low-Middle & Low-Middle & 2.4 & 2.3 & 4.1 & & 747 \\
Tajikistan & Low & Low & Low & & 2.1 & 2.0 & & 733 \\
Ukraine & Low-Middle & Low-Middle & Low-Middle & 2.4 & 2.6 & 2.2 & & 1908 \\
Uzbekhistan & Low & Low & Low-Middle & 2.9 & 2.2 & 1.7 & & 926 \\
Russia & Low-Middle & Upper-Middle & Upper-Middle & 2.7 & 2.4 & 2.2 & & 2111 \\
Poland & Upper-Middle & Upper-Middle & High & 4.0 & 3.4 & 5.0 & Yes & 1928 \\
Romania & Low-Middle & Upper-Middle & Upper-Middle & 2.6 & 3.0 & 3.8 & Yes & 1396 \\
Serbia & — & — & Upper-Middle & & 2.8 & 3.5 & & 901 \\
Kazakstan & Low-Middle & Low-Middle & Upper-Middle & 2.3 & 2.6 & 2.7 & & 1379 \\
Moldova & Low & Low-Middle & Low-Middle & 2.1 & 2.9 & 3.3 & & 887 \\
Bosnia \& Herzegovina & Low-Middle & Low-Middle & Upper-Middle & & 2.9 & 3.0 & & 743 \\
Azerbaijan & Low & Low-Middle & Upper-Middle & 2 & 2.2 & 2.3 & & 900 \\
Macedonia (FYROM) & Low-Middle & Low-Middle & Upper-Middle & & 2.7 & 3.8 & & 736 \\
Armenia & Low-Middle & Low-Middle & Low-Middle & & 2.9 & 2.7 & & 896 \\
Kyrgyzstan & Low & Low & Low & & 2.3 & 1.9 & & 610 \\
Estonia & Upper-Middle & Upper-Middle & High & 5.6 & 6.4 & 6.6 & Yes & 662 \\
Czech Republic & Upper-Middle & Upper-Middle & High & 3.7 & 4.3 & 4.9 & Yes & 859 \\
Hungary & Upper-Middle & Upper-Middle & High & 4.9 & 5.0 & 5.1 & Yes & 1151 \\
Lativa & Upper-Middle & Upper-Middle & High & 3.7 & 4.2 & 4.5 & Yes & 651 \\
Lithuania & Upper-Middle & Upper-Middle & Upper-Middle & 4.8 & 4.8 & 4.9 & Yes & 681 \\
Slovakia & Upper-Middle & Upper-Middle & High & 3.7 & 4.3 & 4.5 & Yes & 665 \\
Slovenia & High & High & High & 6.0 & 6.1 & 6.6 & Yes & 687 \\
Bulgaria & Low-Middle & Low-Middle & Upper-Middle & 4.0 & 4 & 3.8 & Yes & 1853 \\
Croatia & Upper-Middle & Upper-Middle & High & 3.8 & 3.4 & 4.1 & Yes & 1160 \\
Montenegro & — & — & Upper-Middle & & 2.8 & 3.9 & & 153 \\
\midrule
      & & & & & & & Total & 26903 \\
 \bottomrule
\end{tabular}}%
\captionof{table}{Countries in Sample}\label{tab:addlabelB}%
\end{minipage}

%%
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]