# Sideways table takes new page

Tags: tables, appendices, rotating

I am writing a report and I want to place a big `sidewaystable` inside an appendix. More specifically, this appendix does not contain anything else but the table.

```
\newpage\begin{appendices}

\section{References}
%\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{References}

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{bibliography}

\newpage
\section{Pitch - Frequency Table} \label{pitchfrequency}
\begin{sidewaystable}[htbp!]
\begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
  ...a lot of cell data...
\end{tabular}
\caption{Something.}
\end{sidewaystable}

\end{appendices}
```

I want the result to be one page for the appendix **Pitch - Frequency Table**, consisting of the appendix name and the table. However, the above code creates two pages, one for the appendix name and one for the sideways table. Any tips?

These are the two pages shown in Overleaf:

[image: table]

**THIS CAN BE REPRODUCED HERE:**
https://www.overleaf.com/9856935hhnzmbvssdhw

Comment: presumably it's too big to fit under the section heading but as you have shown no example, or said how big the table or your page is,  impossible to suggest  any change.

Comment: I just added a picture of the table. Please do tell me if you need anything else.

Comment: A ful MWE would be nice, so we don't have to guess what packages to load.

Comment: it is virtually impossible to tell anything from an image, (questions are always clearer if they provide an example to reproduce the problem) but as i say it's presumably just too big stick `\small` before the `\begin{tabular}`

Comment: From the manual: two new environments, sidewaystable and sidewaysfigure, each of which produces a `single page-size float` with contents rotated ±90 degrees;

Comment: I added a link to reproduce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will rotate the caption.

```
\documentclass{ieeetran}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
\begin{appendices}

\section{References}
%\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{References}

%\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
%\bibliography{bibliography}

\newpage
\section{Pitch - Frequency Table} \label{pitchfrequency}
\vfil
% get width of tabular
\sbox0{\begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
  ... & a & lot & of & cell & data & ...
\end{tabular}}
{\centering
\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\begin{minipage}{\wd0}
\usebox0
\captionof{table}{Something.}
\end{minipage}}%
}
\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

Comment: We need to enclose the `\centering` in a group; the OP asked [another question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/375631/centering-continues-to-next-page-after-sideways-table) about this.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR -  I never really wondered about how to end \centering before.

Answer (score 3):

As noted in my comment, `sidewaystable` creates a page-size float regardless of its contents.  You can do the following.  Provided that there's room on the page, things can work out as desired.  If you're desperate then you can use the `float` package with [H] option.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{rotating}

\begin{document}

\appendix

\section{References}


\newpage
\section{Pitch - Frequency Table} \label{pitchfrequency}
\begin{table}[h!]
\rotatebox{90}{ \begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
        ...a lot of cell data...
    \end{tabular}}
\caption{Something.}
\end{table}



\end{document}
```

Comment: If the caption needs rotating as well, see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/69287/586

Comment: That answer dominates mine, so I'll vote to close this question.